# Set Minimum value of a group of variables in linear programming

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm trying to use linear programming to find a viable solution for assigning weights to a group of variables.

For example, assume we have two groups of variables like this:

```py
import pulp

w = LpVariable("w", 0, 10)
x = LpVariable("x", 0, 10)
y = LpVariable("y", 0, 10)
z = LpVariable("z", 0, 10)
```

I want to set constraints so that either w or x is greater than zero and either y or z is greater than zero. The number of constraints in each group can be more than two. because of that, I don't want to use if-else statements.

Comment: Is it OR or XOR? What I mean is, can both be greater than zero?

Comment: They can both be greater than zero, but we can't have all of the same group as zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that they can both be zero, instead of only one, just take the sum of the two variables and say that that has to be greater than zero.

```
w + x > 0
```

If `w = 0`, then `x > 0`, and if `w > 0`, then `x >= 0`.

Comment: In linear programming there is no concept of ">" (greater), only ">=" (greater or equal). You could change the 0 for 0.1 or 1 for example and it would work... it would depend on the precision you want to give your variables. Also, you should consider making the variables integer or binary.